# How do I change the background colour behind my webview for the status bar in an iOS7 phonegap/cordova app?

Tags: cordova, ios7, statusbar

As I'm sure you're all aware, Apple have changed the way status bars work in iOS7 which is causing all sorts of headaches with cordova/phonegap apps.

I've managed to push the view down by 20px if the device is running iOS7 using the following code:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    // handling statusBar (iOS6) by leaving top 20px for statusbar.
    screenBounds.origin.y = 20;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
}
else {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
}
```

The problem is, the 20px gap that this code has created has a black background like this:

[image: Black status bar with white text]

How do I change the background colour of this space that my code has created?

In my MainViewController.xib, the background colour is set to white. Where is this black background colour attribute coming from?

Here are the attributes for my MainViewController.xib:

[image: MainViewController.xib attributes]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using Phonegap?

I think you need to use CSS to add margin INSIDE the top of your UIWebView instead of moving the UIWebView down.

Try this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (parseFloat(window.device.version) === 7.0) {
      document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
    }
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using cordova 3.0. I used that javascript code but it doesn't work with absolutely positioned elements. I wanted to find a native solution so that I don't have to continually add conditional stlyes to absolutely positioned elements depending on OS version. I've just run my app on my iPhone 5 and it behaves differently to the simulator; the view is not pushed down by 20px and the background is white.

Comment: So its only a problem in the simulator?

Comment: The iOS7 simulator displays the status bar in the same way that iOS6 does i.e. black background, white text, which is correct except that I want the black background to be white. On the device my code to push the view down is somehow ignored and the status bar is transparent and overlays the view but this is a different issue!